# Saved Media file has unsupported type using sharp in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sharp

I am trying to fetch the image from a remote url, resize it and save it to my computer locally. For this, i am using got library which returns a buffer. i take that buffer and resize the image and then store it in a file using sharp js. Here is my code:

```
module.exports =  async function resize() {
    const url = 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1636838123974-c94c6904b97a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80';

const readStream = await got(url).buffer();
const resizedBuffer = await sharp(readStream).resize(200, 200);
const storedValue = await resizedBuffer.toFile('output');
console.log("resized buffer", resizedBuffer);
console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------")
console.log(storedValue);
return "ok";
```

}

The `console.log(storedValue)` gives:

```
{
  format: 'jpeg',
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  channels: 3,
  premultiplied: false,
  size: 5432
}
```

However, the output image is not shown as a jpeg by my windows machine.
It shows like this: [image: the file name output is the output]

The filename output is the output from the code above. hacker is a random unused jpg image. specifying output.jpg to the file does give me a jpg image but the input can be any format jpg, png, gif so, i need to have the same extension as the media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharp generates the image without an extension because you don't supply one. The first argument for [`toFile`](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#tofile) is `fileOut`, which represents the path to write the image data to. Since the string "output" doesn't have an extension specified, the image is generated without an extension as that is what we tell it to do.

If you utilize the `format` parameter of your user defined `resize` function, then you can supply a media extension in the function calls and the generated images will have the expected extension types.

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://images.unsplash.com/";
const imgUrl = "photo-1636838123974-c94c6904b97a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80";
const fullUrl = `${BASE_URL}${imgUrl}`;

async function resize(url, format, width, height, filename) {
    const readStream = await got(url).buffer();
    const resizedBuffer = await sharp(readStream).resize(width, height);
    const storedValue = await resizedBuffer.toFile(`${filename}.${format}`);
    console.log("resized buffer", resizedBuffer);
    console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    console.log(storedValue);
    return "ok";
}

resize(fullUrl, "png", 200, 200, "foo");
// generates foo.png (image of 3 croissants on a plate)

resize(fullUrl, "jpg", 200, 200, "bar");
// generates bar.jpeg
```

Or if you choose to not define a `format` parameter for the `resize` function, you can grab the image extension from the `resizedBuffer`. I looked through the output and found `options` contains a key `tiffCompression` which defines the media extension type that Sharp received from the `readStream`.

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://images.unsplash.com/";
const imgUrl = "photo-1636838123974-c94c6904b97a?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80";
const fullUrl = `${BASE_URL}${imgUrl}`;

async function resize(url, width, height, filename) {
    const readStream = await got(url).buffer();
    const resizedBuffer = await sharp(readStream).resize(width, height);
    const format = resizedBuffer["options"]["tiffCompression"];
    const storedValue = await resizedBuffer.toFile(`${filename}.${format}`);
    console.log("resized buffer", resizedBuffer);
    console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------")
    console.log(storedValue);
    return "ok";
}

resize(fullUrl, 200, 200, "foo");
// generates foo.jpeg (image of 3 croissants on a plate)
```

Comment: The function contains no parameters. Sorry, i didnot modify the function. i need to get the extension/ format of the remote uri and save the file as same format as received from remote url.

Comment: Ok I see, will update my answer to account for that shortly.

Comment: Hey, i tried it this way. i saved the information about content-type by await got(url) and used the mime-types npm package to get the extension and added it to toFile method.

Comment: @Nothing You can grab the extension type from `resizedBuffer["options"]["tiffCompression"]` as well if you don't want to introduce any new dependencies like `mime-types`.

Comment: Oh, i see. your solution is better. Thank you for helping.